# Trigonometric second-order ordinary differential equation

Tags: calculus, analysis

I hope you're all having good days. I'm just trying to get a second pair of eyes on this thing I've been staring at for hours and can't find anything about online. I promise this is not a homework question.

I am trying to find the Green's function for a second-order non-homogenous linear ODE with a bunch of Lorentzians in it, and have beaten the problem down until it looks like this

$$\frac{d^2y}{dw^2} + [2a^2(1-\tan^2(aw))+ba^4\sec^4(aw)]y = 0$$

ie it's second-order, linear, has a lot of trigonmetric functions in it. Nothing I try helps, but then again I'm only a physicist. If this thing has a name I don't know, or there's an easy technique for it that's escaping me right now, I'd be very grateful for any guidance.

Comment: `Maple 2020.1.1` can solve.Solution by `HeunC` function. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeunC.html

Comment: $$y \left(w \right) = 
\frac{\mathit{c1} \mathit{HC}\left({0, -\frac{1}{2}, 2, -\frac{b a^{2}}{4}, \frac{3}{4}+\frac{b a^{2}}{4}, -\frac{\sin \left(a w \right)^{2}}{\cos \left(a w \right)^{2}}}\right)}{\cos \left(a w \right)^{2}}+\frac{\mathit{c2} \sin \left(a w \right) \mathit{HC}\left({0, \frac{1}{2}, 2, -\frac{b a^{2}}{4}, \frac{3}{4}+\frac{b a^{2}}{4}, -\frac{\sin \left(a w \right)^{2}}{\cos \left(a w \right)^{2}}}\right)}{\cos \left(a w \right)^{3}}
$$

Comment: What was the equation before you applied the trig substitution?

Comment: Also you should at least substitute $u = aw$ and $k = ba^2$ to reduce the parameter count.